# Using ADO .NET convert datatime from sql Server to DateTime in VB .NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services, ado.net, datatable

I have created a Web Service in Visual Studio 2005, using VB .NET language. This Web Service interacts with a database on Sql Server through ADO .NET. 
Using ADO .NET I get one table with this code

```
    conn = New SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString)
    sqlcmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    sqlcmd.Connection = conn
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "select * from myTable" 
    da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
    table = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(table)
```

where Utilities is a class created by me for managing and return ConnectionString.
The table myTable contains more than one field of String type and just one field of datetime named LastChangeDate.
I want select all the dates found in the rows of myTable so I use this code:

```
     Dim d As DateTime 
     For Each row In table.Rows
          d = row.Item("LastChangeDate")
          '
          ' other codes for managing the retuned dates
          '
```

The problem is that after this operation d contains NULL value.

What can I do for convert correctly the datetime returned from Item method into DateTime in VB .NET

Comment: If the `LastChangeDate` column in your database allows NULLs then you can't convert a NULL to a date. You need to check for NULL values before trying to convert this into a date using `row.IsNull("LastChangeDate")`

Comment: I know by my databese does not contains any NULL value in LastChangeDate field.

Comment: Then I think what you mean is that d contains `Nothing` the anser from @shahkalpesh should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dim isDate as Boolean
dim lastChangeDate as Date

isDate = Date.TryParse(row.Item("LastChangeDate"), lastChangeDate)
If isDate Then
  '** code that should work with the extracted date ...
End If
```